# Does Donald Trump have a position on funding of United Nations?

Tags: united-states, united-nations

There exists a populist right wing opinion<sup>[1]</sup> that UN funding from US should be meaningfully diminished (or US should get out of UN, as the more extreme position), due to UN pursuing agenda that is often anti-US-interests.

Does Donald Trump have an position on the topic? (either explicit, or inferred by specific cabinet picks?). 2016+ position preferred, but past statements are OK as evidence as well.

---

[1] Examples:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_withdrawal_from_the_United_Nations)
- [Fox News](http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2015/06/16/america-pay-way-too-much-for-united-nations.html)
- [Thetower.org](http://www.thetower.org/article/the-twisted-conundrum-of-funding-the-united-nations/)

Comment: That depends on who last talked to him and how much they flattered him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donald Trump suggested in a tweet in September 2011, that US should **defund UN** if "UN grants the PA statehood". (Referring to Palestine as PA)

> We must stand firm against the UN's ploy to sabotage Israel---if the UN grants the PA statehood then we must immediately defund it.

[image: Donald Trump on UN funding]

In another tweet, he said "US should look at future funding" of the UN.
[image: Donald Trump questions funding UN by the USA]

> Why is the UN planning to attack @Israel's sovereignty and ignore Iran's nuclear program? The US should look at future funding.

In may 2016, Trump vowed to cut off funding to U.N. climate change programs, [ABC News reported](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/donald-trump-vows-cut-us-funding-climate-change/story?id=39410375).

> Donald Trump unveiled his energy vision for the United States at a petroleum conference in North Dakota Thursday -- **vowing to cut off funding to U.N.** climate change programs and attacking Hillary Clinton.

On Oct. 31, 2016, Trump said at a rally in Warren, Mich that he will put America first and "cancel billions in climate change spending for the United Nations", [BNA reported](https://www.bna.com/trump-says-plan-n57982082131/).

> “We’re going to put America first. **That includes canceling billions in climate change spending for the United Nations**, a number Hillary wants to increase, and instead use that money to provide for American infrastructure including clean water, clean air and safety,”

Comment: @user4012 I updated the post.